# How do I cut off excess overlap of two objects?

Tags: modeling, objects, bisect

How can I cut off (delete) the excess parts of the logs sticking through the roof in my picture?

Note: The sloped roof is just a rotated plane; not sure if this affects how you might do it.

[image: My UE4 asset]

Comment: Would be easier if you give the roof planes thickness first. (cubes instead of planes)  In Edit mode drag the log vertices back inside the roof's thickness.

Comment: In most situations (everywhere you want less polygons) you don't want to cut these intersections. This will create additional geometry because that's the only way to point where certain mesh should end is create there edges. If this is for printing then indeed geometry should be cut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A practical way to do this is:

- Go into an orthogonal view looking down the edge of your plane roof
- In Edit Mode, Put (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) 2 edge loops around your log
- Slide (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) each of your edge loops until they coincide with the slope, top and bottom.
- With the knife tool, cut through (<kbd>K</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) from the top vertex of the left loop to the bottom vertex of the right loop.
- Rip (<kbd>V</kbd>)the newly created sloping edge loop.
- Select linked (hover <kbd>L</kbd>) on the left side of the new loop, and delete faces.
- Dissolve your guide loop, if you like.

[image: Sloped cut]

But you're still in trouble: If your roof is a simple plane, either the logs will show through, or there will be a gap on the outside, or you will have coincident geometry, which will cause artifacts. So really, your roof should have some thickness, and the ends of the logs should be concealed inside it.

Comment: ....but check out @ Duarte Farrajota Ramos comment/answer: it's neater, here.